# Is it possible to dynamically change values in the index.html file for Flutter web?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter

If I have a chat script as follows:

```
<script src="https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js"></script>
<script> window.fcWidget.init({token:"123456",host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com",siteId:"SiteName",externalId: "test@gmail.com",firstName:"Name",lastName:"Vermeulen",email: "test@gmail.com",config: {content: {actions:{csat_yes:'Yes',csat_no: 'No',push_notify_yes: 'Yes',push_notify_no: 'No',},}}});</script>
```

Is it possible to dynamically set variables for index.html? If so what would be the best way to accomplish this? I want to dynamically set the values (name, surname, email etc) when the user signs in on the web application.

Any suggestions will be appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you do it in Flutter side and by preferences for saving?

Comment: By flutter side do you mean render with an iframe widget? I would like to avoid this if possible and directly use/alter the index.html file.

Comment: Never try this, but my idea is save those variables value in a text under web asset, then make your script to read and use its string tag from those asset file.